# Получение объекта класса с помощью рефлексии

Tags: java, рефлексия

Пытаюсь заменить рефлексией следующий код:

```
CData cData1 = new CData();
CData cData2 = new CData();

cData1.setData(с1);
cData2.setData(с2);

parentCData.addCData(cData1);
parentCData.addCData(cData2);
```

Получается как-то так:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    Class classObj = CData.getClass();
    Method methodSetId;
    Class[] paramTypes = new Class[] {int.class};

    try {
        methodSetId = classObj.getMethod("setId", paramTypes);
        String answer = (String) methodSetId.invoke(X, i);
        parentCData.addCData(Y);
    } catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Но я не понимаю, что должно быть в этом коде вместо `X` и `Y`... Ну, то есть понимаю, что вместо Y вроде должен быть объект класса CData, но как его получить? И по поводу X всё ещё более непонятно...

Comment: ну так объект у которого ты хочешь вызвать эти методы. на сколько я понимаю в данном случае X==Y

Comment: вместо X должно быть classObj

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, почему? просто `obj`, `classObj ` - Это ж класс

Comment: @Grundy,  а как в моём случае можно получить `obj`?

Comment: @Ksenia, создать его :-) `new CData()`, либо через рефлексию. А `setId` - это статический метод или обычный? По идее если статический, тогда  `classObj` можно передать

Comment: Кстати, а зачем тут вообще рефлексия?

Comment: @Grundy а, ну да... наверное надо типа `Class obj = Class.forName("com.test.classes.CData");` и уже его совать. ты об этом?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не понял :-) для чего надо?

Comment: @Grundy, ну тут упрощённый пример кода, а вообще там кроме cData1 и cData2 есть ещё cData3, cData4 и т.д.

Comment: @Ksenia, проще всего положить эти объекты в массив - и никакой рефлексии не надо :)

Comment: @Grundy, точно, как-то я сразу об этом не подумала... :)

Comment: @Grundy ну шоб создать экземпляр. типа `Class clsobj  = Class.forName("com.test.classes.CData");
   Object obj = clsobj.newInstance();` - что-то типа такого

Comment: Первым аргументом в объект метода передается тот объект, на котором его надо вызвать, последующие - непосредственно аргументы метода.

Comment: @etki, с этим вроде разобрались :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Class classObj = CData.getClass();
try {
    Method methodSetId = classObj.getMethod("setId", int.class);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        Object X = classObj.newInstance();
        methodSetId.invoke(X, i);
        parentCData.addCData(X);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // TODO: log exception ;)
}
```